# Define pointcut to capture an interface but not parent or sub interfaces

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, pointcut

I was wondering how to define a pointcut in aspecJ that captures any method of an interface but not the methods of any parent or sub-interface.

```
public interface A {
  void methodA();
}

public interface B extends A {
  void methodB();
}

public interface C extends B {
  void methodC();
}
```

I would like a poincut that only catches methodB() and not methodA() or methodC(). Is there any way i can do this in a general way without listing all the sub and super interfaces in the pointcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find direct inheritance is not possible with Java or AspectJ.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried B.methodB(..) or B+.methodB(..) or even B+.*(..) AspectJ method patterns?